# converting a flat list to a nested dictionary based on items from the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

For example, I have a flat list like this:

```
[' a',
'  aa1',
'   aaa1',
'   aaa2',
'   aaa3',
'   aaa4',
'   aaa5',
'  aa2',
'   aaa6',
'   aaa7',
'   aaa8',
'   aaa9',
'   aaa10',
' b',
'  bb1',
'   bbb1',
'   bbb2',
'   bbb3',
'  bb2',
'   bbb4',
'   bbb5',
'   bbb6',
'  bb3',
'   bbb7',
'   bbb8',
'   bbb9',
'   bbb10']
```

I need to convert to a nested dictionary like this:

```
{'a': {'aa1': ['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5'],
       'aa2': ['aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8', 'aaa9', 'aaa10']},
 'b': {'bb1': ['bbb1', 'bbb2', 'bbb3'],
       'bb2': ['bbb4', 'bbb5', 'bbb6'],
       'bb3': ['bbb7', 'bbb8', 'bbb9', 'bbb10']}}
```

each item from the list concludes spaces, the item with only one space is assigned as the top key to the nested dictionary, the one with two spaces is assigned as the second level key to the previous item, and then with three spaces items are all the values for the previous key.

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Comment: At what point are you stuck?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Including an interrogative sentence in your post, would help us to know what you are asking. (And make the question appropriate. Sentences like "Where can I find help with my homework?" are not appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

I think the spaces only make the list awkward, you don't necessarily need them to achieve what you want.

First, `strip` all the spaces from the list items, then build the dictionary starting off from [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). The logic that does what you intended to do with the spaces is `re.sub`. Applied to clear out all the numbers, the length of the string after substitution can now be used to determine its position in the dictionary:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

# remove all spaces from list items
lst = map(str.strip, lst)

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for i in lst:
    j = re.sub('\d+', '', i)
    if len(j) == 1:
        k1 = i
    elif len(j) == 2:
        k2 = i
    else:
        d[k1][k2].append(i)

pprint(d)
#{'a': {'aa1': ['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4', 'aaa5'],
#       'aa2': ['aaa6', 'aaa7', 'aaa8', 'aaa9', 'aaa10']},
# 'b': {'bb1': ['bbb1', 'bbb2', 'bbb3'],
#       'bb2': ['bbb4', 'bbb5', 'bbb6'],
#       'bb3': ['bbb7', 'bbb8', 'bbb9', 'bbb10']}}
```